# Java Aggregator for Akka

Tags: java, akka, aggregation, integration-patterns

I am trying to implement a Java [Aggregator](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/Aggregator.html) for Akka, [since it doesn't look like](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/2In6ovNOfUg) the Java API supports them (**why not!?**)

Here's my best attempt thus far:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
abstract class Aggregator<T> extends UntypedActor {
    ActorRef recipient
    Set<T> aggregation
    // TODO: Timer timer (?)

    abstract boolean isAggregated()

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        aggregation << message as T

        if(isAggregated()) {
            recipient.tell(new Aggregation(aggregation))    // again, pseudo-code
            aggregation.clear()
            // TODO: timer.reset()
        }
    }
}
```

What is missing is some kind of a `Timer` construct that will time the `Aggregator` out after, say, 60 seconds if it has not aggregated yet. On timeout, it should throw some exception of some sort. On aggregation, the timer should be reset. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `ReceiveTimeout`. Akka provides a feature to have a timeout when a particular actor has not received anything in a predefined amount of time.

In Java you would do something like this inside your actor:

```
getContext().setReceiveTimeout(Duration.create("1 second"));
```

When this trigger it sends a message of type `ReceiveTimeout` to the actor and then you can decide what you want to do (exceptions, logging, resetting...).

You can find more information here under the section 'Receive timeout': http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/untyped-actors.html

On the other hand, there are open-source libraries to do these kind of things available in github. Take a look to https://github.com/sksamuel/akka-patterns for more examples.

Comment: Thanks @hveiga (+1 and green check) - with regards to the GitHub libs, the one you linked is a 100% Scala library. My *understanding* is that I can't just plop a Scala jar into my Java project. Is that incorrect? Could I actually use this lib in my Java actor system, instead of reinventing the wheel myself here? Thanks again!

Comment: That is true. It will just work if the authors of the library have put together some kind of Java API for it which doesn't seem the case. However, you can take a look to the code for the `Aggregator` and get ideas to develop your own version. Sorry for the misunderstanding between Scala-Java.